# How to structure mono repo in python using anaconda to import from same namespace?

Tags: python, pip, conda, monorepo

I want to build a mono repository that uses heavily (git) submodules and anaconda for the build process / dependency resolution. Here is a simplified birds eye view of the mono repo (python projects / packages).

```
├── awesome_pkg
│   ├── awesome_submodule1
│   └── awesome_submodule2
├── environment.devenv.yml
├── readme.md
└── setup.py
```

Each submodule than again has its own dependencies and basically is a package on it's own. I want to bring them together in the awesome_pkg and use environment.devenv.yml based on the specific build instructions to select the subpackages to my liking / deployment use-case.

By nature of the submodules (they stand on their own) I am not sure how to achieve the following two things in particular:

1. Install the mono repo under a shared common namespace. For example I would then do:

```
from awesome_pkg import submodule1
```

How can I achieve this?

2. Keep the individual submodules functional in a sense that the tests run through etc. despite of the changed imports.

I should note that the final package (awesome_pkg) is in most cases installed via pip -e . to enable development.

Is this the correct set-up (idea)?